# How to record multiple changes from multiple sheets through Worksheet_Selection change in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I have 5 sheets in my workbook.Whenever I make a change in any of the sheets cell I want to record the change and create new log sheet with sheet name, which cell was updated,what is the updated value etc.

How can I do this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to use the SelectionChange event, simply enable the built-in 'Tracking changes'.  This logs all changes internally which can then be displayed in-cell or, as you desire, listed on a separate sheet.

Guide for Excel 2003 (and earlier)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-gb/excel-help/turn-on-change-tracking-for-a-workbook-HP005201213.aspx

Guide for Excel 2007 (and likely Excel 2010 aswell)
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/track-changes-in-a-shared-workbook-HP010197381.aspx